# Joining of two tables without any primary key both tables have foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables :

List(lid,list_name)
Phone(pid,lid,phno)
Emails(eid,lid,email)

Tables having records as shown here

### List

```
lid ----------- list_name

**1** ------------- **ads**

**2** ------------- **visits**
```

### Phone

```
pid ------- lid ----------- phno

10 ---------**1** ---------- 9988123456

20 ---------**1** ---------- 9988123454

30 ---------**2** ---------- 9988222222

40 ---------**2** ---------- 9988333333
```

### Emails

```
eid ------- lid ----------- email

1 ---------**1** ---------- xyz@abc.com

2 ---------**1** ---------- abc@abc.com

3 ---------**2** ---------- list2@abc.com

4 ---------**2** ---------- list21@abc.com
```

I want to create join between Table Emails and Phone with foreign key lid.

I tried it like this

```
SELECT * FROM phone left join emails on phone.lid = emails.lid WHERE 1
```

and got output form this query

```
pid -- lid ---- phno ---------- eid --- lid --- email

10 ----- 1 --- 9988123456 -- **1** --- 1  --- xyz@abc.com

20 ----- 1 --- 9988123454 ---**1** --- 1  --- xyz@abc.com

10 ----- 1 --- 9988123456 ---**2** --- 1  --- abc@abc.com

20 ----- 1 --- 9988123454 ---**2** --- 1  --- abc@abc.com

30 ----- 2 --- 9988222222 -- **3** --- 2  --- list2@abc.com

40 ----- 2 --- 9988333333 ---**3** --- 2  --- list2@abc.com

30 ----- 2 --- 9988222222 ---**4** --- 2  --- list21@abc.com

40 ----- 2 --- 9988333333 ---**4** --- 2  --- list21@abc.com
```

Here you can see we are getting duplicate emails and duplicate phone number, but I want the result that there should not be any duplicate email and duplicate phone in any row they both must be unique as shown below:

```
pid -- lid ---- phno ---------- eid --- lid --- email

20 ----- 1 --- 9988123454 ---**1** --- 1  --- xyz@abc.com

10 ----- 1 --- 9988123456 ---**2** --- 1  --- abc@abc.com

30 ----- 2 --- 9988222222 -- **3** --- 2  --- list2@abc.com

40 ----- 2 --- 9988333333 ---**4** --- 2  --- list21@abc.com
```

I'm stuck here. Please suggest me the solution.

Comment: How do you know which phone number goes with which email address?

Comment: Essentially you want two tables side by side. As Tim asked, you have to provide details on how to match emails and phones... and you also have to tell what you expect should there be a different number of phones and emails for a single lid.

Comment: there is no matching pattern, i need to fetch say 20 emails and 20 phone numbers for common list id and want to send sms and email. The only requirement is i want to create single query. there may be possibility number of emails are different then number of phone numbers

Answer (score 0):

Your table structure would not allow you to get the output you expect. 
In table Phone (according to given data) *lid* cannot be a candidate key. Same goes to *lid* in table Emails.

*lid* cannot be used as a foreign key. **A foreign key must reference either the primary key or a unique key(candidate key) of the parent table.** But this is not the case in either tables.

I would suggest introducing a new column to get the one-to-one mapping you need

Comment: thanks for answer i will try on it. if solved i will post here